# Wants to call methods from string but using prototype doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hashmap, prototype

Wants to make class method that receives string and returns function. First I made it using switch method. It is an example and there would be more methods in myMethod and also another myMethod like myMethod2.

```js
// using switch
class MyClass {
  constructor(a, b, c, d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.e = d;
  }

  myMethod(methodName) {
    switch (methodName) {
      case "addA":
        return (num) => {
          this.a += num;
        };
        break;
      case "addB":
        return (num) => {
          this.b += num;
        };
        break;
      case "mulA":
        return (num) => {
          this.a *= num;
        };
        break;
      case "mulB":
        return (num) => {
          this.b *= num;
        };
        break;
      default:
        return () => {};
    }
  }
}

const obj1 = new MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4);
obj1.myMethod("addA")(3);
obj1.myMethod("mulB")(4);
console.log(obj1); // {a:4, b:8, c:3, e:4}
```

So I can call methods from string and functions can be divided into types.
then I tried this switch style to lookup function table.

```js
// using hashMap
class MyClass {
  constructor(a, b, c, d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.e = d;
  }

  myMethod(methodName) {
    const methods = {
      addA: (num) => {
        this.a += num;
      },
      addB: (num) => {
        this.b += num;
      },
      mulA: (num) => {
        this.a *= num;
      },
      mulB: (num) => {
        this.b *= num;
      },
      // and many more methods
    };
    return methods[methodName];
  }
}

const obj1 = new MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4);
obj1.myMethod("addA")(3);
obj1.myMethod("mulB")(4);
console.log(obj1); // {a:4, b:8, c:3, e:4}
```

My first question is when calling this method, do myMethod makes methods object(methods ={ // string => function hash map } ) every time?

I thought it is true. So I tried to add methods object to prototype.

```js
// prototype
function MyClass(a, b, c, d) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.d = d;
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = {
  addA: (num) => {
    this.a += num;
  },
  addB: (num) => {
    this.b += num;
  },
  mulA: (num) => {
    this.a *= num;
  },
  mulB: (num) => {
    this.b *= num;
  },
  // and many more methods
};

const obj1 = new MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4);
obj1.myMethod["addA"](3);
obj1.myMethod["mulB"](4);
console.log(obj1); // {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4} failed
```

Then it fails. If an answer of my first question is false, I'll do that way. Or is there a way to work in a prototype way? I'm trying to learn how to write prototype but I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `this` context looks on `myMethod` object. You don't have any variables in this object that you declared in `MyClass`

Try to declare `myMethod` via anonymous function (read comment in code)

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
// here you have context `this` of MyClass
// you can save `this` in variable and use it in object below
return {
addA: function(num) {
  console.log(this);
  this.a += num;
},
addB: (num) => {
  this.b += num;
},
mulA: (num) => {
  this.a *= num;
},
mulB: (num) => {
  this.b *= num;
},
// and many more methods
}
};
```